# Не срабатывает проверка

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

В тексте нахожу слова начинающиеся с `@`, требуется проверить: если в конце этого слова стоит знак пунктуации - удалить его, и в итоге записать в список все эти слова с отсечением `@`.

Мой код:

```
from string import punctuation
text = '@user1: bla bla bla @user2 @user3.'
for word in text.split(" "):
    for p in punctuation:
        if word.startswith('@') and word.endswith(p):
            users_list.append(word[1:-1])
        if word.startswith('@') and not word.endswith(p):
            print(word)
            users_list.append(word[1:])
```

удаление `:` и `.` не происходит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предложу более простое решение без костылей:

```
import re
from string import punctuation

text = '@user1: bla bla bla @ab.abd:, @user2 @user3.'

users_list = [re.sub(f'[{re.escape(punctuation)}]+$', '', user_name[1:])
              for user_name in text.split()
              if user_name.startswith('@')]

print(users_list)
```

Вывод:

> ['user1', 'ab.abd', 'user2', 'user3']

Comment: Спасибо большое, не сталкивалась с translate))

Comment: `maketrans` - очень медленная. Подстановка не зависит от текста, желательно делать её один раз.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy буду знать, спасибо!